# python pandas datafream to_csv index

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i get some info from api Companies House

```
df = pd.read_csv(company_numbers_file)
print("datafrem")
print(df)
print("datafrem")
test =[]
i=0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    company_number = row["Company Number"]
    resultQuery = requests.get(search_url.format(company_number), auth=(key, ''))
    if resultQuery.status_code == 200:
        result = json.JSONDecoder().decode(resultQuery.text)
        test.append(result['items'][0]['company_number'])
        test.append(result['items'][0]['title'])
        cars = {'companynumber': [result['items'][0]['company_number']] ,
                'title': [result['items'][0]['title']]
                }

        dff = pd.DataFrame(result['items'][0]['company_number'], index= [i] ,columns= ['companynumber'])
        i=i+1
        print(dff)

dff.to_csv('Name.csv',index=False)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWglk.png)
here I print dff and I got all value correct
but when I convert it to csv i get the last value only !!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIWWq.png)

```
    datafrem
  companynumber
0      SC341963
  companynumber
1      03369488
  companynumber
2      03369488
  companynumber
3      03369488 ....etc


  companynumber
4      03369488
  companynumber
5      03369488
  companynumber
6      03369488
  companynumber
7      03369488
  companynumber
8      03369488
  companynumber
9      03369488
   companynumber
10      03369488
   companynumber
11      03369488
   companynumber
12      03369488...etc
```

the file Name.csv got this only

```
companynumber
11605899
```

Comment: because with each loop you create a new dataframe and then you save to csv only the one created in the last loop

Comment: How to create empty datastream and apend df to ?